# Why wouldn't Python code run in a Jupyter notebook when it runs in the terminal?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've replicated [Slack's API demo](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/tree/master/tutorial) in a text editor and the terminal, but just for fun, I wanted to do it again using Jupyter notebook. I used the same virtual environment so as to rule-out dependency issues and the code was the same (cloned from the master repo). But for some reason, I'm always getting ModuleNotFound errors when I try to run the code in Jupyter cells and import the necessary packages.

I even re-built a fresh virtual environment, and ran the demo at a terminal from within Jupyter, and running the scripts works fine. I just doesn't execute in the notebook environment.

I'm using the same kernel across my Python interpreters, and I always start my virtualenv session before launching the notebook.

Anyone have any ideas why this would be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, DUH. It was just a matter of uninstalling/reinstalling the package in a fresh virtual environment (and I'm pretty sure the latter wasn't absolutely necessary).

Thanks to [this comment on Github](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/issues/439) for the guidance.